# Messaging Service that works like Guava's EventBus

Tags: java, guava

Currently we are searching for a in-JVM messaging solution that provides the same slick API as  the newly introduced Guava EventBus does. EventBus provides almost all necessary features but we are missing persistence and the ability to restrict handlers to a certain rate. We do not need the enterprise functionality that projects like ActiveMQ or HornetQ provide. Although the ability to run multiple nodes of our application is maybe an option later on. I would be really grateful for any pointers in the right direction.

Another possibility would be to extend the Guava EventBus with a HornetQEventBus (similiar to the ASyncEventBus) or implementing our own facade for JMS. Barebones JMS just feels a bit bloated for our purposes and I personally find the EventBus API a really good fit for our use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'd advise going ahead and extending EventBus, if you can.  (I'm not sure we expose EventHandler and some of the other components you'd need, though.  =/)

I recall that there had been some discussion among the Guava team on a Guava "throttling" API; I'm not sure how far along that got, whether there are any plans to release it, or whether it could be mixed nicely with EventBus.

Comment: Well as you indicated EventBus is not really designed with extensability in mind, so we will be settling for rolling our own implementation which might be a little more feature loaded than the guava eventbus.

Answer (score 1):

Well at present it is not possible to override the dispatch method of the EventBus there is a ongoing debate on the same and you can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=780)